# Counting occurrences with SELECT DISTINCT, SELECT COUNT and UPDATE in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

In Access, I have a table like this one:

```
Date      | EmployeeNum | Award
11-JAN-08 | 34          | GoldStar
13-JAN-08 | 875         | BronzeTrophy
13-JAN-08 | 34          | BronzeTrophy
18-JAN-08 | 875         | BronzeTrophy
```

And I want to have a table count them like this:

```
EmployeeNum | GoldStar | BronzeTrophy
34          |    1     |      1
875         |    0     |      2
```

I want to be able to generate this table by running a query or something similar.  I've tried putting this into a query but I'm not really sure I'm doing it right.  I've tried using UPDATE and SET = SELECT COUNT without too much success.

How should I do this?  SHOULD I be trying it like that?

Answer (score 3):

You will need a crosstab (aka pivot) query for that. Try the following SQL and modify to suit your needs:

```
TRANSFORM Count(MyTable.EmployeeNum) AS AantalVanEmployeeNum
SELECT MyTable.EmployeeNum
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY MyTable.EmployeeNum
PIVOT MyTable.Award;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Access, try "/View/Pivot Table View".

Answer (score -1):

I would use the query below to get your totals:

```
SELECT EmployeeNum, 
       SUM(Case [Award] WHEN 'GoldStar' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As [GoldStar], 
       SUM(CASE [Award] WHEN 'BronzeTrophy' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As [BronzeTrophy]
FROM MyTable
Group By EmployeeNum
```